# log info is showing in embedded jetty but not when app is deployed to tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, log4j

My log4j properties file looks like this:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.category.org.springframework.web=INFO
log4j.category.org.springframework.samples.mvc31=INFO
```

When I run my app in embedded jetty by `mvn jetty:run` I see the logger info from my code, stuff like : `logger.info(myobj)`

However, when I package the app using `mvn package` and deploy it to tomcat, I don't see the logs.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no console in Tomcat, so by default your console output is dumped to a file named catalina.out.  Do you not have that file?

Comment: I have catalina.out localhost.out and localhost-access.out however, none of them contain the log messages. Do I need to create a separate file in my log4jproperties?

Comment: If you want to control where it's logged, setting up a FileAppender or RollingFileAppender in your log4j config is the way to go (and the way I'd recommend).  If You prefer to use the default logging (java.util.logging), check out conf/logging.properties.